# Fast simple object serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am looking for fastest serialization method tiles in 2D world. Lets say the world is big and because computer can't handle that much blocks loaded at the same time, so I splitted the world to chunks. `BinaryFormatter` seems to be slow. Is there any faster method, how to serialize the chunk object?

WChunk object structure

```
public class WChunk
{
    public int ChunkX;
    public int ChunkY;
    public SortedDictionary<WPoint, WTile> Tiles;
}
```

WTile object structure

```
public class WTile
{
    WPoint Location;
    int Data;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fastest option I'm aware of is [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).

There is a performance comparison here (thanks @Andrei)

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/08/performance-test-binaryformatter-vs-protobuf-net/

[image]

.NET implementations

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/

Comment: Comparison between protobuf-net and binary formatter http://theburningmonk.com/2011/08/performance-test-binaryformatter-vs-protobuf-net/