# Most efficient solution for sending large Xml strings over WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, serialization

I need to send and receive objects that contain a few small fields, plus one large Xml string, via WCF, like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Xml {get; set;}
}
```

I must use an Http based binding, but the service is internal, so contract dlls will be shared. The Xml string could reach a few MB. The service allows transfer of data between servers via the client machine, so the first client call retrieves a large lump of Xml, saves it to local disk, then a second call transfers the data from disk to another service instance on some other box somewhere else. So the client literally saves the data and forwards it, no logic or processing at all.

I need the most efficient mechanism - meaning small payload, and fast - for sending these objects.

Some questions:

- What is the most efficient way of sending a large chunk of Xml in a payload?
- Is there any advantage in serializing the object to a `MemoryStream` before sending across the wire using a `BinaryFormatter` and then using a `Stream` type as the parameter in the service operation?
- For messages of a few MB, does using a `Streamed` transfer mode make any difference?

I can't use third party libraries like Protobuf-net (sadly).

Appreciate any advice...

Answer (score 2):

For a start, I'd send it as an `XmlNode` rather than a string:

```
[DataMember]
public XmlNode Xml {get; set;}
```

which avoids all the encoding of XML tags.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer of data = time to prep on server + transfer time + time to process on client.

I'd guess that the transfer time is considerable.  I've had luck solving that problem before by serialising to XML, zip-compressing the resulting string, then either sending a byte array or serialising the zip-compressed string to base64.

It adds processing time, but nowhere near as much as the transfer time for the uncompressed version was taking.

Standing/startup data for the app in question to cache on startup is several megabytes uncompressed, used around the world and so in lower-quality connection areas, compression is necessary..

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> Is there any advantage in serializing the object to a MemoryStream before sending across the wire using a BinaryFormatter and then using a Stream type as the parameter in the service operation?

implies that you don't really need to send `Xml`, but rather the object that is currently serialized into `Xml`.

If so, you will get the fastest serialization and best compression using [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) rather than BinaryFormatter.

For more information and a comparison see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550778/141172

**UPDATE**

If you were referring to serializing `ServiceResponse` with a BinaryFormatter, Protocol Buffers will still offer superior performance.

Comment: "a few small fields, plus one large Xml string". He's not saying the object is serialized into XML, but that the object CONTAINS an xml string. Having said that, I think your answer is still correct.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, can't use protobuf. On the Xml, no this is not a representation of an object, it is actually Xml data. So I'm suggesting converting the Xml to binary.

Comment: @MalcomTucker: Why no protobuf, when BinaryFormatter is an option?

Comment: At this stage I can't add third party dependencies. That may change, but right now that's the situation. Plus I was hoping for a few answers that would explore the options, rather than simply stating 'use protobuf'. I know about protobuf, and I knew people would fly in with that, but I'm interested in a deeper answer :)

Comment: How does pre-serializing and sending a `Stream` parameter, differ from just sending binary over Http via the web service binding? Does it offer anything on the client side? Is the payload smaller? Is it identical (ie. does WCF just use the BinaryFormatter behind the scenes)?